# Is this lazy variable initialization pattern bad practice?

Tags: javascript

Coming from the rubyesque crowd I was very fond of the following 'lazy' initialization pattern.

```
myhash[:property]||='value'
```

And sometimes during my career I adapted it to javascript as following:

```
myhash.property || (myhash.property = 'value')
```

A co-worker remarked that it's quite irregular, and to be honest I can't remember seeing other people using that pattern.

So my question is; Is it just another innocent initialization flavor or am I unintentionally asking for trouble?

Given the execution flow of conditional statements like that I suppose It is possible to use it as an `if` statement aswell:

```
aModel.valid && aModel.save();
```

or even something more insane..

```
willYouMarryMe === 'yes' && (function(){
  console.log('Wohoo!');
})();
```

Comment: Remember that JavaScript has many more false-y values than Ruby: sometimes you want a 0 to stay a 0. As far as code style, I *avoid* strict side-effects in conditionals, as I find it harder to understand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lazy initialization is often used in JavaScript, but it's more common to see:

```
namespace.property = namespace.property || 'default';
```

As far as calling functions is concerned, it's good practice to use `if` statements where they apply instead of `&&` and `||`. Minifiers will often automatically convert the `if` statements into `&&` and `||` for production to reduce file size, so it's not necessary to do so directly.

Writing easily readable code makes future maintenance easier:

<sub>Good:</sub>

```
if (!foo) {
    bar();
}
```

Writing code that's harder to read makes code harder to maintain. Particularly because using one clever trick often indicates that other clever tricks are going to be used:

<sub>Bad:</sub>

```
foo || bar();
```

The one major exception to this with regard to functions tends to be when calling `console.log`:

```
window.console&&console.log('lorem', 'ipsum');
```

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much answers my question. My followup question would be, is it safe to expect that expression evaluation behaves the same across different js-engines? Somewhere i get the feeling that there might not be an explicit prohibition to evaluate the right-hand expression if the former expression is false in the ECMA standard. ( Gee.. I probably should go dig there for further info )

Comment: @telamon, it sounds like you're asking whether the short-circuit evaluation behavior of the `&&` and `||` operators is part of JavaScript as a language, or whether it's just part of some implementations. If I've interpreted your question correctly the answer is that it's a defined behavior as part of the ECMAScript standard (`&&` and `||` will not evaluate the second argument unless the first argument is truthy or falsey respectively). If I've misunderstood your question, please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks, you nailed it! In retrospect that was exactly the question I've been searching for.